# Business Central APIConnect With Xamarin Forms using Azure AD

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

```cs
public class EmployeeAbsenceService
{
    private HttpClient _client;
    private readonly string webAPI = "https://xxxxxx";

    public async Task<ObservableCollection<EmployeeAbsence>> GetData()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(webAPI);
        var myToken = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("AccessToken");

        HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
        message.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", myToken);
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(message.ToString());
            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<EmployeeAbsence>>(content);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I access the token by using securestorage, it's working fine.

I'm trying to get the data from business central, but the error message:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Can you add exceptions' stack trace?

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: @Cheesebaron `HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(message);`

Comment: Where do you create your instance of `_client`?

Comment: private HttpClient _client; @Cheesebaron

Comment: But you never assign it, that is why it is null

Answer (score 0):

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
> of an object

You are trying to use something that is null. This means you either set it to null, or you never set it to anything at all.

From the code you posted,we found that you created variable `_client` ,but you didn't assign a value for it before using it:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(message.ToString());
```

So, you can assign a new instance to it before you use it, for example:

```
_client = new HttpClient ();
```